# Mobile User checkbox not appears in user detail in developer sandbox and UAT even user having API Enable permission in profile

Tags: profile, administration, mobile, user-management, user-record

and Production i am able to see mobile user checkbox.
[image: you can see here dev sandbox not found mobile user checkbox]Mobile User checkbox not appears  in user detail in dev sandbox  and UAT but its appeared in dev 2 sandbox instance.

[image: I can see mobile user permission in dev2 instance But not in developer instance and UAT]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce has planned to retire the Salesforce mobile web experience with the Summer ’20* release.

Kindly review below link.

[Salesforce Mobile Web Experience Retirement](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?language=en_US&type=1&mode=1&id=000349471)

Comment: Thanks @vinay, providing correct answer